# How to Persist an extra column(attribute) in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've been having some difficulties implementing an extra column in a many-to-many relationship using jpa and hibernate.

I've already tried many times but didn't succeed. The only way I've got things to work was with a simple many-to-many relationship, with no extra columns and no new  entity created. The code I've given below it's working but it doesn't include the extra entity desired, called "CandidateLanguage", so I can add an extra attribute.

```
//CANDIDATE CLASS
//imports
@Entity
@Table(name="candidates")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdat", "updatedat"}, allowGetters =
true)
public class Candidate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String fullname;
private String address;
private String birthdate;
private String placeofbirth;
private String hobbies;
private String presentation;    
private int yearsofexperience;

@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
private Date createdat;

@Column(nullable =false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date updatedat;



public Candidate(String fullname, String address, String birthdate, String placeofbirth, String hobbies, String presentation, int yearsofexperience) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.address = address;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
    this.placeofbirth = placeofbirth;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.presentation = presentation;
    this.yearsofexperience = yearsofexperience;
}


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        })
@JoinTable(name = "candidate_languages",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "language_id") })
private Set<Language> languages = new HashSet<>();

//getters and setters



//LANGUAGE CLASS
//imports
@Entity
@Table(name="languages")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Language {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NaturalId
private String idiom;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
},
        mappedBy = "languages")
private Set<Candidate> candidates = new HashSet<>();

public Language() {

}

public Language(String idiom) {
    this.idiom = idiom;
}
//getters and setters
```

The objective is to persist another column called "writting", which is a skill level in terms of language knowledge and has levels "C1", "C2", "B1", "B2", "A1", "A2" and "Native" (maybe an enumerated?). 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't set them up like this. If you want to persist additional information to a many-to-many mapping, you need to create a separate entity and map that entity to the mapping table. Then you use simple `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` mappings in your code accordingly. Read more [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply @XtremeBaumer! I will try to implement with Vlad's method. Cheers

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [the following approach](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/0320__JPA_ElementCollection_MapKeyEntity.htm), if you can live with converting the `languages` property into a `Map<Language, Level>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @crizzis. If the first method doesn't work I will try your suggestion. Cheers